# Move Magento 2 Admin to Subdomain

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2, ssl

Is it possible to run the Magento admin from a subdomain? 
I.E. 
https://d1.com - live site
admin;
https://backend.d1.com/admin

I've attempted alias/park domain and a view other things (of course setting the custom url in Config > Admin ) but it usually just gets stuck in a redirect loop going to https://backend.d1.com/admin

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution.? Please share here.

Comment: I went a different route for the issue I was having so stopped pursuing it.

Comment: May i known, How you solved that issue.?  Share here that will be greatly appreciated

Comment: My issue was related to Cloudflare so unless you are dealing with a cloudflare issue, it's unlikely to help you.

Comment: Yes, i'm also using the cloudflare. IS cloudflare is causing this issue??

Comment: Well Magento takes a long time to do some tasks, like uploading a lot of images, which causes Cloudflare to error out during it. It's been a while but I believe the fix was to whitelist all of cloudflares IPs in the firewall.

Comment: Hi, i had already whitelisted all the cloudflare IPs on my server firewall. But this timeout error is coming on some tasks like sending a push notification via google firebase / sending a sms to customers.  Cloudflare support agent said to create a subdomain and use grey cloud for admin. But magento not supporting subdomain. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes! There is a possiblility to run from a subdomain.

Along with Aman's answer, you need to mask and forward the subdomain (https://backend.d1.com) to main domain (https://d1.com) in your domain settings.

For reference, see [this](https://in.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422)

Comment: Welcome Bhargava!! Instead of posting links that may someday be broken, post the answer contained in the link instead. You can give credit to the site. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible you can set the custom admin URL from Magento backend/admin

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Admin -> Admin Base URL -> Use Custom Admin URL (Yes) -> Custom Admin URL
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I've attempted that, I setup an alias/parked backend.domain.com and pointed the admin url there, but it has redirect issues. There may also be CORS isssues.

Answer (score 0):

Is this of any help? https://gist.github.com/tegansnyder/65ba3396ec7cbf70bec9

I think it's for Magento 1 but principle should be the same?

Comment: Yeah I did attempt that. I gave up anyways though honestly. I think there may have been CORS issues but surprisingly couldn't find anyone else attempting it. The reason I was attempting it I found an alternate solution to.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for Magento 2 is pretty simple:

Just configure as the main domain name (default value): backend.domain.com. So the admin will be available at backend.domain.com/admin.

Change scope to the storeview, and enter www.domain.com as the store domain name. So the store will be available at www.domain.com.